# Can I replace my road bike's front wheel quick release with any quick release?

Tags: quick-release

I lost my road bike's quick release. Pictured are what I lost. Do I need to find a specific quick release that fits, or does one size fit all/most?

[image: This whole thing here is what I lost]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep. Quick releases are standard and interchangeable.

You need to make sure you get one the right length for a front hub. Front hubs for a road bike, hybrid or older MTB will be 100mm wide.

Comment: There are a few cases where the lever of one type of QR will interfere with the frame or accessories on the bike, so a different style of lever is needed.  But this is usually obvious when you try to use the QR and the lever keeps hitting stuff.

Comment: @Argenti Apparatus: Since QR are usually sold in pairs it would be a good idea for OP to buy a matching pair where the second one also fits the rear, either for a short rear axle (road bike) or for a long rear axle (MTB).

Comment: @Carel I did not research if QRs are sold individually. The OP may have to buy a set. Personally I'd buy a set as I'm OCD enough to want them to match :-)

Comment: @DanielRHicks : If the levers interferes with other hardware it is either poorly designed or badly positioned. Position is easiest to adjust. With disk-brakes the front QR is often better at the ride side to avoid hand contact with a hot rotor.

Comment: Some QRs may be sold individually. One bike store near me (link to follow) lists front Salsa skewers. Salsa is a Quality Bicycle Products brand. QBP is a major distributor of bike parts, and almost all bike stores should have an account with them, so the OP should be able to order his/her front skewer. Not all stores might have one black front skewer in stock, of course. https://www.freewheelbike.com/product/salsa-front-stainless-flip-off-skewer-243572-1.htm?variations=1611596&buylocalRequestId=13717930&buylocal=2649550&utm_source=Salsa-BuyLocalNow&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=BuyLocalNow